# Apache rewrite exclude empty URI

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite

The following rewrite appends .html to the URI.
`RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /sites/uk/$1.html [NC,L]`

However, when it comes to the index page it is giving me:

`.../sites/uk/.html` instead of:
`.../sites/uk/index.html`

What I want to know is how to exclude an empty URI so it doesn't append .html to nothing. I have tried the following rewrite condition:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$` However this is unsuccessful.

Comment: Well if you request `/sites/uk/`, then that is not exactly `/`, is it? Perhaps you want to match request URIs that _end with_ a slash instead …?

Comment: I don't quite follow @CBroe but I appear to have found a way to do it using these two rules instead: `RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /sites/ie/$1.page [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /sites/ie/index.page [NC,L]`